# React npm module default css is getting overridden by the base application css

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a react npm module which uses default antd css. antd version is 5.7.3. When I install this to a base react app it overrides the default css in the npm module. The react base application has css modules which has override the default antd css. Is there a way to stop overriding the default antd css of the npm module.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `!important` to your css props file. If you don't antd will override css props related to default styles.

Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76875250/9894625) answer I've made. It have an example.